# Highlight for Current Menu Item not highlighting correctly Online

Tags: php, highlight

I am building the website and everything is fine in Localhost but when I made it online the active menu is not highlighted. Can you please help me to resolve it.

But when I create subfolder it works.

My code goes here :

```
<?php
$filename = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$filename = substr($filename, 9);


?>
```

**HTML :**

```
<header id="header" class="container navbar">



                <nav id="menu" class="nav-collapse collapse default-menu">


                <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="nav">



                    <li <?php if($filename=='about-us'){?>class="current_page_item"<?php } ?>>
                    <a href="about-us" class="dropdown-toggle order" data-target="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>

                    <li <?php if($filename=='offers'){?>class="current_page_item"<?php }?>>
                        <a href="offers" class="order">OFFERS</a>

                    </li>


                    <li <?php if($filename=='membership'){?>class="current_page_item"<?php }?>>
                        <a href="membership" class="order">MEMBERSHIP</a></li>



                </ul>       
            </nav>
           <div class="clear"></div>   
    </header>
```

Please someone help me !

Answer (score -2, accepted):

first try echo your $filename value what you getting and match like below

if your $filename has correct value then try to echo your text

```
<li <?php if($filename=='about-us'){echo 'class="current_page_item"';} ?>>
```

try with

```
$info = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $filename = $info['filename'];
```

Comment: Thank you rakesh ji for the reply. I tried it. in localhost it show correct file name and everything works fine but Online echo shows nothing. So dont know what to do!

Comment: try to echo your $filename

Comment: I echo but display is blank! It shows nothing! In localhost it shows filename correctly.

Comment: check what is requert_uri you get and substr() you need to try basename() http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_filesystem_basename.asp

Comment: Everything working perfectly in Localhost and no response online. Fed up !

Comment: i think you need to try with basename() get your page name with this function and match it

Comment: Dear Rakesh,  Finally I made it with basenam(). Thanks a lot for your help. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you ! But how to accept the answer ? Confused!

Comment: Dear Fren Can you solve this problem too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181493/i-need-full-background-image-on-the-column-even-there-is-no-texts#